# grammar 만들어: 우리는 매년 가족들과 송편을 만들어 먹어요

Tags: grammar

우리는 매년 가족들과 송편을 **만들어** 먹어요.

I am a bit confused with the grammar used in 만들어 as above. 
What is the grammar point relating to 어 in 만들어 here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 어 is from the [~아/어(서) clause connector](https://www.howtostudykorean.com/unit-3-intermediate-korean-grammar/lessons-67-75/lesson-70/). The sentence is saying, "Every year our family makes and eats rice cakes." and the 어 is essentially the "and" in the sentence, but see the link for the subtleties as it is not a direct translation.

Comment: Thanks. What is the meaning of 어서 in 있어서 here? 전자회로의 설계에 있어서 부귀환은 매우 중요하면서도 편리한 개념이다.

Comment: The 어서 is the same pattern there, but with the optional 서 attached. In the link I listed above, they go into detail about when it is optional or not; however, your sentence seems to be missing a word between 설계에 and 있어서 and I'm not sure what 부귀환은 means (did you mean 부귀한??), so I'm struggling to give you a better answer because I don't fully understand the sentence. Can you check if you transcribed it correctly, and I would also love it if a native speaker could keep me honest here because it's totally possible I'm just missing something.

Comment: 부귀환 is probably a translation of negative(부) feedback(귀환).  @anhnha is probably looking at a university-level electrical engineering text, or something similar.  (Not sure exactly how popular the term is: I suspect many engineers might be more comfortable with just saying 네거티브 피드백 these days.)

Comment: @jick ah, thanks! Is it just me, or does it seem like 있다 is missing a compliment in that sentence?

Comment: Hi, jick is right. 부귀환 is negative feedback here. The whole sentence means "Negative feedback in the design of electronic circuits is a very important and convenient concept." However, I don't understand the usage of 어서 here.

Comment: @anhnha I just asked a native speaker, and the "~에 있어서" is a somewhat idiomatic phrase meaning "in terms of." It does come from the same grammar point I mentioned, but since it's idiomatic, it doesn't follow the same rules exactly. So, a more literal translation would be, "In terms of electronic circuit design, negative feedback is a very important and convenient concept."

Comment: Thanks. That is exactly what I was confused. Your translation makes perfect sense. I tried to apply the meanings "because, therefore" or sequence but it doesn't fit at all.

Comment: Yes, "~에 있어(서)" is an idiom: I think it is used more frequently in writing than in speech.